# Driver design tips for YIG

Tags: operational-amplifier, driver

starting  a driver design for YIG input is 1mV output 25mA
Specifications: 
BW of 2MHz will be good. 
10mW input needs to be interpret into 30mA threw load coil. 
The FM coil data: 
sesitivity: 450 KHz/mA 
3dB bandwidth 2.2MHz 
resistance 2Ohm 
inductance 1.5uH 
I was recommended me to use a combination of AD8033 and a MOSFET \
by the structure shown below.
The main thing I need it to be stable and low noise, In LTSPICE I can see only the general functionality. Is there are recommendations? what MOSFET to use? what opamp to use in order lower noise ?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please give more details about the loading coil. "450 KHz/mA" seems not to define it at all. Try and use proper punctuation to mark the end of one sentence and the begining of the next.

Comment: 450kHz/mA would be the system-level sensitivity. With the YIG element installed in the coil, the resonant peak shifts 450kHz per each mA of coil current.

Comment: Josh23 - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link for the source of that copied image. (And please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future). TY

Answer (score 0):

Many op-amps will have real trouble with stability with 1kΩ series resistance in their power input lines. I would advise not going there - it's only a solution that works with particular op-amps, usually older bipolar types, and is an unnecessary kludge.

> I was recommended me to use a combination of AD8033 and a MOSFET by the structure shown below.

Has someone who recommended it actually tried it with that particular op-amp? Because I give it 50/50 odds of never working correctly. It'll happily oscillate.

Instead, I'd use a "boring" class-A output stage. It's pretty much guaranteed to work on the first try.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffFOys.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 is the class-A load that sources idle current. OA1+M1 are a constant current source. Rs is the current sense resistor that senses the current flowing through the coil.

The DC transconductance is:

$$ g_m = \frac{1}{R_s}. $$

As shown, since \$R_s=1{\rm\,\Omega}\$, the transconductance is 1mA/mV, so a +50mV input drives a positive 50mA current through the YIG. The current drive is bipolar. The maximum absolute current is limited by R2: the higher the R2, the lower the absolute current that can be driven into the YIG coil.

The specs for the circuit that you've mentioned are somewhat self-contradictory so I've set \$g_m=1{\rm\,S}\$. You can set it to whatever you need by adjusting \$R_s\$.

With a +/-2.5V supply, OA1 can be any of the modern rail-to-rail output types. The input common mode voltage to OA1 is a bit above 0V, so shouldn't be a big concern unless \$R_s\$ will be increased.

Comment: Hello ,Could you please reccomend an opamp and mosfet models which i could simulate and see in LTSPICE?